# Salesforce Leads: URL field

Tags: php, web2lead

**Issue:**
I have a URL field called `CampaignLink__c` which I pass a URL to, however, the url that is inserted is malformed.

**Desired Result:**
Inserting a URL to a custom field of the Lead object on Salesforce.

**Description:**
This is a Web-To-Lead form with this code:

```
<input type="hidden" name="CampaignLink__c" value="www.schechter.org.il/land/landing/mishley/?f=facebook-ctw-Jerusalem/">
<input type="hidden" name="ArticleName__c" value="land/landing/mishley/">
```

I tried to insert a URL with http or without but all I get is this:
`http://facebook-ctw-Jerusalem`, also tried with `urlencode()`, same result.

Any idea why the URL is not inserted as it looks on the form HTML? how can I check for something like "input mask" or "input validation" (not sure of the terminology on Salesforce) for that field in Salesforce.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried debugging this by enabling debug logs? By adding a debug statement in before trigger operation?

Answer (score 0):

As that is a URL, you have to URL encode it.

so if URL was "www.schechter.org.il/land/landing/mishley/?f=facebook-ctw-Jerusalem/"

it will be

```
www.schechter.org.il%2Fland%2Flanding%2Fmishley%2F%3Ff%3Dfacebook-ctw-Jerusalem%2F
```

Comment: Same thing, URL is malformed in the same way.